# Are Rails 3 Subdomains Fairly Painless?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I have an app with two sections, Buyers and Sellers. The main section '/' is for Buyers, but I have a separate Sellers portal that I'm currently placing in /sellers. Might be nicer to move the sellers to their own subdomain like 'sellers.mydomain.com'.

Subdomains don't seem to be extremely popular and I've read things like they make testing difficult, etc. Wondering what you all have to say about the issue.

Comment: Since I first asked this question, I have to say YES, they are quite painless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that make testing a bit of pain with subdomains, but introducing subdomains as a real supported feature in rails 3 has somewhat mitigated these problems.

**EDIT**: Adding something like this to your test helper can make testing a lot easier and more readable.

```
  def set_subdomain(sub)
    @request.host = sub.present?? "#{sub}.test.host" : "test.host"
  end
```

**EDITx2**:

http://www.railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: That is the old Railscast, here is the new one for Rails 3: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: Would namespacing be an issue at all? So I everything I have in /sellers now I can easily put in its own subdomain?

Comment: Namespacing in terms of what? The scope of routes?

Comment: I haven't done testing yet, but the regular routing using subdomains seems to be pretty painless. Just throw everything you normally would inside a constraints block.